# Check Theme Compatibility when upgrading from Magento 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: magento, themes, upgrade

We have a magento store on 1.7 and want to upgrade to 1.9. We have a self-made theme on the 1.7 store and want to take it with us to the 1.9 version. Is this possible or not? Magento 1.9 brings a lot of changes to the design and I don't know how to check the theme's compatibility.

If it's possible, how can I check the compatibility without installing a new shop system and copying the theme into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take backup first of source and database 
when you upgrade magento it will override base and default theme files if you have place your changes within theme folder then it will not affect.
You can upgrade magento from system -> magento connect manager -> check upgrades -> then select latest modules and click on save